# Simplest way to test installation of R package on fresh R install?

Tags: r

I would like to test that I've set up my package dependencies and imports correctly. I think the best way to check is on a fresh R install, but I don't want to delete all my existing libraries to do this test.

Is there a relatively painless way for me to quickly create an isolated R instance with only base libraries and test installation? Preferably with the ability to tear the whole thing down easily once I'm done.

Comment: If you already have anaconda python installed. You can create a virtual environment, which isolates the contents, you can install anything you like into it and then dissolve it all by uninstalling it the environment.

Comment: Thanks, I was already looking into that or Docker, conda seemed a bit easier to manage, shame it doesn't have up to date versions of R though.

Comment: I have R installed in my jupyter notebook environment. It may not be the very most recent, but it has done everything I asked of it so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Anaconda/miniconda installed on my computer and it can be used to create an R environment

```
conda create -n r-dev -c r r-essentials
```

unfortunately on my machine `ElementaryOS Loki 0.4`. This does not set up tk/tcl properly, running `conda install tk`, `conda install tcl` does not help, the consequence being that `install.packages()` will fail when searching for a CRAN mirror. I only need devtools so the workaround is to use

```
conda install r-devtools
```

furthermore I require bioconductor packages, so I need

```
R>source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
R>biocLite("BiocInstaller")
```

This completes my required environment and I then use `devtool::install_github()` to test the installation of my package.

Answer (score 1):

You can (rather easily) use the 'library path' appropriatetly -- for example via environment variables `R_LIBS` and/or `R_LIBS_USER`.  Other options are to set `.libPaths()` directly.  Full details are in `help(Startup)`.

That, combined with a package without additional dependencies, should do.

Here is a little demo, simply using a file `~/.Renviron` in the current environment.  I have nothing but "base R" and its packages visible:

```
edd@brad:/tmp/libDemo$ cat .Renviron 
R_LIBS=""
R_LIBS_USER=""
R_LIBS_SITE="/usr/lib/R/library"
edd@brad:/tmp/libDemo$ Rscript -e 'print(.libPaths())'
[1] "/usr/lib/R/library"
edd@brad:/tmp/libDemo$ Rscript -e 'print(installed.packages()[,1:2])'
           Package      LibPath             
base       "base"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
boot       "boot"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
class      "class"      "/usr/lib/R/library"
cluster    "cluster"    "/usr/lib/R/library"
codetools  "codetools"  "/usr/lib/R/library"
compiler   "compiler"   "/usr/lib/R/library"
datasets   "datasets"   "/usr/lib/R/library"
foreign    "foreign"    "/usr/lib/R/library"
graphics   "graphics"   "/usr/lib/R/library"
grDevices  "grDevices"  "/usr/lib/R/library"
grid       "grid"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
KernSmooth "KernSmooth" "/usr/lib/R/library"
lattice    "lattice"    "/usr/lib/R/library"
MASS       "MASS"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
Matrix     "Matrix"     "/usr/lib/R/library"
methods    "methods"    "/usr/lib/R/library"
mgcv       "mgcv"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
nlme       "nlme"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
nnet       "nnet"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
parallel   "parallel"   "/usr/lib/R/library"
rpart      "rpart"      "/usr/lib/R/library"
spatial    "spatial"    "/usr/lib/R/library"
splines    "splines"    "/usr/lib/R/library"
stats      "stats"      "/usr/lib/R/library"
stats4     "stats4"     "/usr/lib/R/library"
survival   "survival"   "/usr/lib/R/library"
tcltk      "tcltk"      "/usr/lib/R/library"
tools      "tools"      "/usr/lib/R/library"
utils      "utils"      "/usr/lib/R/library"
edd@brad:/tmp/libDemo$
```

Comment: The point is to test the dependencies of my package, that everything is properly installed and functions will run as expected. Essentially I'm worried that my package may be missing dependencies in the DESCRIPTION, which I would not notice as I already have all the required packages on my system.

Comment: See my expanded answer.  Just now define, say, `R_LIBS_USER=/tmp/libDemo/lib` and install into that.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, unfortunately I seem to have polluted all of my standard `.libPaths()`, my `/usr/lib/R/library` is the cleanest and even that contains the whole of Hadley's tidyverse and all of Bioconductor's base dependencies.

Comment: Just base R libraries to a new "clean" directory and start from there.  Or, if your system is messed up like that, use Docker which I quite like a bit too.

Comment: And _of course_ another alternative is to use Travis CI off a GitHub repo as many of us do.

Comment: I ended up using conda because I was more familiar with it than Docker.